# Walter Feit's program for characterizing $S_5$.

Tags: gr.group-theory, reference-request

In Jacobson's Algebra Vol. I, there is a long, 10 part exercise which characterizes $S_5$ as isomorphic to any finite group having precisely two conjugacy classes, such that the centralizers of the distinct representatives of these classes are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times S_3$ and a dihedral group of order $8$.

In an aside in the text, Jacobson notes that this program was communicated to him by Walter Feit. Is there any knowledge of whether this result ever published in any paper by Feit, or simply a result spread by word of mouth? If the former, does anyone have reference to where it appeared?

Comment: I think you mean "two conjugacy classes of involutions"